# Method signature changes after adding WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

In my solution I have a create a WCF service which takes message contract class as parameter.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceClass
{
    [OperationContract]
    Employee AddEmployee(Employee employee);

}

 public class ServiceClass : IServiceClass
 {
    public Employee AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
       //do something
    }
 }

[MessageContract]
public class Employee
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am adding this service to my client application using Add service reference option. The service added successfully.
Then in my client program I used this method. But the method signature has been changed. It changed as follows.

```
 public void AddEmployee(ref string EmployeeNumber, 
    ref System.DateTime DOB, ref string FirstName, ref string LastName)
```

I am using the service in the client as follows.

```
TcpServiceReference.ServiceClassClient service =
            new TcpServiceReference.ServiceClassClient();
```

NOTE:TcpServiceReference is the service name

I cant understand the reason.

Comment: Are you sure that signature doesn't exist somewhere else in the client code that is being picked up by the IDE? Try searching for it and see if you find another instance.

Comment: Belogix: I looked in the Reference.cs class the method accept the Employee class is in the ServiceReference.TcpServiceReference.IServiceClass but its not in the ServiceReference.TcpServiceReference.ServiceClassClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure why WCF does this some times, but if you use the service interface, you'll get the "correct" method signatures:

```
TcpServiceReference.IServiceClass service = 
    new TcpServiceReference.ServiceClassClient();
```

(this is assuming that `IServiceClass` is the *client-side* name of the service interface that svcutil (Add Service Reference) has generated for you.)

Comment: This works for me. But I can not understand why its happening.If I add a method with out parameters its appear correctly in the TcpServiceReference.ServiceClassClient.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure either. I've never had it happen when consuming my own WCF services, only when accessing the PayPal services. I guess it's down to something in the WSDL exposed by the service. Maybe the SOAP version (bindings) have an effect?

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour with Employee as a MessageContract but not when using DataContract. Can it be the difference?

Comment: @Jocke ah, that may be it, I've never used MessageContracts before. They apparently give you more direct control over the SOAP messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved the problem?

Looks like the proxy is not generated successfully, unless you also have a AddEmployee method that returns void (and takes four parameters)?

I would recommend that you re-generate (delete and create) the service reference.

Cheers
--Jocke

Comment: But do you have two AddEmployee methods with different signatures? One that return void and one that returns Employee?